# Can I get postgres to automatically generate ids for pairs of objects using typeorm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

#### Background

Our node app uses a postgres database and interacts with it via [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/#/).

I know how to create a table with a primary key generated by a postgres sequence as [described here](https://typeorm.io/#/entities/primary-columns):

```js
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
}
```

#### Goal

I am trying to create a table for objects that are always created in pairs; let's call the objects "shoes" and say that the two members of the pair are the left shoe and right shoe.  I would like the left and right shoes to be separate entries in my table, and I want to be able to easily query for both shoes in a pair.

One approach would be something like this, which gives me an index on `pairId` and enforces only one left shoe and one right shoe for each pair ([TypeORM index docs](https://typeorm.io/#/indices/indices-with-multiple-columns))

```js
enum Foot {
    Left = "Left",
    Right = "Right"
}

@Entity()
@Index(["foot", "pairId"], { unique: true })
export class Shoe {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: "enum", enum: Foot })
    foot: Foot;

    @Column
    pairId: number
}
```

However, this approach I am still responsible for generating the values in the `pairId` field.

#### Question

Is there a way I can get postgres to generate the values in `pairId` for me?  Perhaps using the same kind of sequence that is automatically generated by the `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` decorator?

#### Update

[Response below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734823/239712) proposes a possible solution in postgres, though I would still need to know how to do this in either by using TypeORM's API or getting TypeORM to run the relevant raw SQL commands at the right time.

I could write a TypeORM [migration](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations) to run the raw SQL, but I'm not sure how to get it to run on table creation -- it seems like the documentation primarily anticipates running them from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can assign a sequence to column in Postgres. First use:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createsequence.html

`CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq OWNED BY shoes.pair_id`

The `OWNED BY` is optional but 'ties' the sequence to the table so it is automatically dropped with the table.

Then you can make the sequence the DEFAULT for the column:

```
test(5432)=# create table shoes (pair_id integer DEFAULT nextval('my_seq'));
CREATE TABLE
test(5432)=# \d shoes 
                          Table "public.shoes"
 Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |           Default           
---------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------
 pair_id | integer |           |          | nextval('my_seq'::regclass)
```

Or for existing table:

```
test(5432)=# create table shoes (pair_id integer);
CREATE TABLE

test(5432)=# alter table shoes alter COLUMN pair_id SET DEFAULT nextval('my_seq');
ALTER TABLE
```

I have no idea how you would do that in TypeORM though.

Comment: Thanks! That gets us at least partway there :-)  Hopefully some TypeORM experts will know how to do this in TypeORM (or at least get TypeORM to execute these SQL commands at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the foggiest idea of TypeORM, but is straight SQL just create a table with a compound key, a generated id and left/right value. You can then insert both  via a single statement.

```
create table shoes (pair_id integer generated by default as identity
                    ,foot    text
                    ,constraint shoes_pk
                                primary key (pair_id, foot)
                    ,constraint foot_check 
                                check (lower (foot) = any('{left, right}') )
                    );                                          
 
with this_pair(id) as
   ( insert into shoes(foot) 
     values ('left')
     returning pair_id 
   )
insert into shoes(pair_id,foot)
  select id,'right'
    from this_pair
returning pair_id ; 
 
select * from shoes;
```